# Edge Detection Point Cloud

Tags: point-clouds, vision, sobel

I am working on a application that is filtering a point cloud from a laser distance measuring device.  Its a small array only 3x176x132 and Im trying to find parts inside a bin and pick the top most.  So far I have played around with filtering the data into a way that can be processed by more traditional vision algorithms. I have been using the Sobel operator on the distance data and normalizing it and this is what I came up with

[image: Sobel Distance Data]

The Same filter applied to the PMD amplitude

[image: Sobel Amplitude Data]

My problem is I feel like I am not getting enough out of the distance data.  When I probe the actual height values I see a drop the thickness of a part around the edges but this is not reflected in the results.  I think it has to do with the fact that the largest distance changes in the image are 800mm and a part is only 10mm but Im sure there must be a better way to filter this.

Any suggestions

Comment: any reason why you don't use the full field of view for the container? Are there bigger containers as well? Every pixel counts. You don't have that many :)  Reflections and smooth surfaces are not good for PMD. They introduce a lot of noise and measurement errors. What are those parts? metal disks?

Comment: Yes. Metal disks. I managed to get a reasonable result but once the stacking pattern changed it turned I decided there simply wasn't enough detail out of this sensor to work. There were physical limitations forcing a minimum distance from the parts to sensor hence the field of view. On to a traditional camera :))